# Change shape of multi-dimensional NumPy array without changing dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am currently monkey-patching a Scikit-Learn function and one of the lines requires a NumPy array with 2 dimensions. However, the data I am working with is a NumPy array with 3 dimensions, which raises the error "too many values to unpack."

I am calling the K-Means function `fit` to cluster the data. My problem boils down to this following line of code, assuming `X` is the `ndarray` that I pass in:

```
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
```

`X` is an array with 3 dimensions, like the following:

```
X = np.array([[[1, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6]],

              [[7, 8, 9],
               [10, 11, 12]],

              [[13, 14, 15],
               [16, 17, 18]]])
```

The data represents a group of time series of data points that have 6 dimensions. For example, the first element, `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]` would represent a time series with samples from 2 time periods, each sample with 3 dimensions.

And I have monkey-patched the `k_means_` code to allow me to perform clustering on an `ndarray` of `ndarray`s. My goal is to perform k-means on 2D arrays.

Is it possible to set the shape of the 3D ndarray to 2 elements? For example, I tried converting the 3D array to a 2D array of objects but it ends up getting converted back to a 3D array.

```
np.array([[x.astype(object) for x in c] for c in combined])
```

Likewise, the following code is also converted back to a 3D array.

```
np.array([[np.array(x) for x in c] for c in combined])
```

The list comprehension `[[x.astype(object) for x in c] for c in combined]` looks like it creates the correct array, but because it is of type list, it no longer works in the function.

I am looking for some way to "convert" a 3D NumPy array into 2 dimensions. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I am not looking for a way to reshape the array. I need to keep all the dimensions but change the shape to ignore one of the dimensions.

Comment: This is likely not possible. But you must tell us what function you are calling for us to be sure.

Comment: Dimensions is the length of the shape tuple. `n_samples, n_features = X.shape` is just a standard Python expression that unpacks a 2 element tuple into 2 variables.  Creating an object dtype array that contains arrays or lists is tricky if all the sublists are the same size.  But even if you succeed it doesn't look like code will be able use it.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, I understand that. My problem is that my `X.shape` has 3 elements and cannot be unpacked into that line of the function. I'm looking for a way to "trick" the line into thinking that `X` only has 2 dimensions, such as if it was a 2D array of `ndarrays` or 2D array of `objects`

Comment: What would the third dimension be? Your example is somewhat lacking.

Comment: @ whoever downvoted me...Why the downvote? At least, please explain why you downvoted. I tried my best to include all the necessary information and to edit the post as requested by the commenters, and I am more than willing to include more information or clarify anything that might be confusing. It doesn't help if you simply downvote without explaining why, especially on a question that is, in my opinion, not in violation of SO rules.

Comment: These aren't just meaningless numbers here. The library expects a 2D array where each row represents the features of a sample. You have... something else. You haven't told us what.

Comment: (You've said it's a 3D array, but you haven't told us what the array means.)

Comment: Okay, you've told us what the array means now. That's good. With the new information, it really looks like you should be flattening the inner dimensions. You can unflatten them later if you want.

Comment: @user2357112 Why does it matter what the array means if I'm asking for how to achieve a general goal of creating a numpy array of numpy arrays?

Comment: @victor: You're not asking how to create a NumPy array of NumPy arrays. You're asking how to "set the shape of the 3D ndarray to 2 elements", which doesn't make sense, and you're trying to solve a problem about k-means clustering. Asking about the meaning of your object is important information both for making sense of the literal question you're asking and for determining if there's a more sensible way to solve your underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an array of arrays, we have to play some tricks, because `np.array` tries to make an as-high dimensional array as it can.  If the subarrays vary in size that is ok, but if they are all the same we have to fight that.

Here's one way:

start with a 3d array:

```
In [812]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
```

and an empty object array of the right size (but flattened)

```
In [813]: A = np.empty((6,),object)
```

copy values (again with flattening), and reshape to the target shape

```
In [814]: A[:]=list(arr.reshape(-1,4))
In [815]: A=A.reshape(2,3)
In [816]: A
Out[816]: 
array([[array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6, 7]), array([ 8,  9, 10, 11])],
       [array([12, 13, 14, 15]), array([16, 17, 18, 19]),
        array([20, 21, 22, 23])]], dtype=object)
```

So now we have a (2,3) array, who's shape can be unpacked.

I tried to start with `np.empty((2,3),object)`, but couldn't get the `A[:,:]=...` assignment to work.  For this object reshaping to work we have to split `arr` into a list of arrays.  An object array is, like a list, an array of pointers.

But will the `scikit` functions accept such an array? (after passing the shape hurdle).  I suspect the object reshaping is a short sighted solution.

---

```
In [824]: [[x.astype(object) for x in c] for c in arr]
Out[824]: 
[[array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=object),
  array([4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=object),
  array([8, 9, 10, 11], dtype=object)],
 [array([12, 13, 14, 15], dtype=object),
  array([16, 17, 18, 19], dtype=object),
  array([20, 21, 22, 23], dtype=object)]]
In [825]: _[0][0].shape
Out[825]: (4,)
```

This creates a nested list of lists, with the inner elements being (4,) object array.  Wrap that in `np.array` and it recreates a 3d array with dtype object.

---

reshaping, which for some unknown reason, you don't want to do preserves the numeric dtype

```
In [828]: arr.reshape(2,-1)
Out[828]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
In [829]: arr.reshape(-1,4)
Out[829]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This worked perfectly to create the ndarray of ndarrays. I had to combine it with tons more monkey-patching, but it finally worked :)